# input of function in php (symfony 2 framework) contain \ what does that do?

Tags: php, symfony

what following function do in php with symfony2 framework?
this function is from symfony book

```
public function setDueDate(\DateTime $dueDate = null) {
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
}
```

and what does input "null" means in definition of function?

Comment: Without ever touching symfony I can tell you that this function sets the due date. Isn't the name of the function enough to make you know what it does?

Comment: The \ is to select the global namespace. To learn more about namespaces check out the PHP-manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the \ is to select the global namespace as Peter Said.

It is set to null as a default value, in case you don't send a value, $dueDate will be set to null.